# Opening a python file in terminal. (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I just installed ubuntu today, and I can't figure out how to run my .py file.

I opened terminal and typed in python test.py and I receive an error saying "python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

If you could please help me out, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the correct command to open it, but there is no test.py file in your current working directory.

Try using

```
ls
```

To verify what files are in fact in your working directory and use

```
cd path/goes/here
```

To change directories to where the file is located.

Then try `python test.py`

Comment: Alright, I gave that a try, however nothing happens.

For example:
george@George:~/this/is/my/path$ python test.py
george@George:~/this/is/my/path$ 

that is what happens

Comment: Type `ls` and hit enter. What is returned?

Comment: you need find the exact location test.py is in.

Answer (score 0):

python test.py  would try to execute the test.py from the current directory.

else try giving the complete path of the test.py

like "python /usr/local/bin/test.py"